# Given a number print the next three numbers

Tags: java, methods, iteration

I'm trying to print out the next three number of any given number but it won't work for any other numbers except 1-5. So how do I adjust it so it works for any given number?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number");
    int num = inp.nextInt();
    nextNums(num);
}

public static void nextNums(int number){
    do{
        number++;
        System.out.println(number);
    }while(number < 5);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a single `number` you could add a second variable to hold the count. Like

```
public static void nextNums(int number){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(number + i);
    }
}
```

Or using a `do while` like

```
public static void nextNums(int number){
    int i = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println(number + i);
        i++;
    } while (i < 3);
}
```

Or, if using Java 8+, with an `IntStream` like

```
public static void nextNums(int number) {
    IntStream.range(number, number + 3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*but how do i skip the first one and print only the next three?*

Like

```
public static void nextNums(int number){
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(number + i);
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void nextNums(int number){
    int i = 1;
    do {
        System.out.println(number + i);
        i++;
    } while (i < 4);
}
```

or

```
public static void nextNums(int number) {
    IntStream.range(number + 1, number + 4).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! but how do i skip the first one and print only the next three?